# How to remove woocommerce error You cannot add another “PRODUCT NAME” to your cart

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

in my website woocommerce settings, remove add to card ajax and notice; and when users (visitors) add a product to basket for buy, redirect after click to basket and show message add product to card successful in basket

but when in product option active (enable) I want to sell alone option.
users try for add product to basket for repeatedly. receive below message:
cannot add another “PRODUCT NAME” to your cart.
my question is How to use functions.php for remove this woocommerce error You cannot add another “PRODUCT NAME” to your cart.

and new message show in basket after repeat click add to cart button in basket
you previously “PRODUCT NAME” to your cart. so now you can pay.

Generally:

1. remove cant add another ... message and stop redirect to product page after click.
2. show new custom message. after click and go to basket.

Thank you very much for all of you

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a tested and working solution to remove the "You cannot add another" message.**

**Background:** Woocommerce does not expose direct hooks to all of its notices. The cart errors are actually hardcoded into class-wc-cart.php as thrown Exceptions.

When Error Exceptions are generated, they get added to a list of Notices that we can access, parse, and alter using the methods:

- **wc_get_notices()** returns all notices as an array
- **wc_set_notices()** lets you set the notices array directly

In order to access the notices and alter them, you need to hook an action that will fire after woocommerce has generated its notices, but BEFORE the page is displayed. You can do that with the action:  **woocommerce_before_template_part**

Here is complete working code that specifically removes "*You cannot add another*" notices:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_template_part', 'houx_filter_wc_notices');

function houx_filter_wc_notices(){
        $noticeCollections = wc_get_notices();

        /*DEBUGGING: Uncomment the following line to see a dump of all notices that woocommerce has generated for this page */
        /*var_dump($noticeCollections);*/

        /* noticeCollections is an array indexed by notice types.  Possible types are: error, success, notice */
        /* Each element contains a subarray of notices for the given type */
        foreach($noticeCollections as $noticetype => $notices)
        {
                if($noticetype == 'error')
                {
                        /* the following line removes all errors that contain 'You cannot add another'*/
                        /* if you want to filter additiona errors, just copy the line and change the text */
                        $filteredErrorNotices = array_filter($notices, function ($var) { return (stripos($var, 'You cannot add another') === false); });
                        $noticeCollections['error'] = $filteredErrorNotices;
                }
        }

        /*DEBUGGING: Uncomment to see the filtered notices collection */
        /*echo "<p>Filtered Notices:</p>";
        var_dump($noticeCollections);*/

        /*This line overrides woocommerce notices by changing them to our filtered set. */
        wc_set_notices($noticeCollections);
}
```

Side note:  If you wanted to add your own notice, you can use wc_add_notice().  You'll have to read the woocommerce documentation to see how it works:
[wc_add_notice on WooCommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_add_notice.html)

Comment: That is sad to hear.  Do you have a workaround to post that will work in the newest version?

Comment: Replace `return (stripos($var,` with `return (stripos($var['notice'],` This way you prevent the **"stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"** warning error 
and it will also fix the issue with this code.

Comment: @brauliobo  Can you try 7uc1f3r's suggestion?  What he said makes sense.  I didn't realize this was generating a warning previously.  I don't have a way to test this myself right now, so I'd like a confirmation if possible before I edit the answer.

Comment: @7uc1f3r doesn't help, I think `wc_set_notices` is being overwritten by a later action, as `var_dump` shows that the notice was matched

Comment: @brauliobo The adjustment does work because I have tested it 2x. Maybe it's because of other plugins / custom code you are already using. Do you just want the message to stop appearing? or do you want to replace it effectively with another message?

Comment: @brauliobo I have tested it again with my adjustment and it does work (WooCommerce 4.6.0). Could you post the result of the `var_dump` before the foreach and after the foreach? 
My result looks like [this](https://pasteboard.co/JwOA3fQ.jpg). Regards

Comment: before: `array(1) { ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["notice"]=> string(176) "Ver carrinho Você não pode adicionar outro "Curso de Formação em Tantra Yoga" em seu carrinho." ["data"]=> array(0) { } } } }`
after: `array(1) { ["error"]=> array(0) { } }`
message still appearing. btw, I had to change to the localized string

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get rid of the message (JamesHoux response doesn't work anymore, even if you empty the $noticeCollections array the notices still appears), maybe you could try change the message with another one:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_product_cannot_add_another_message', function($message, $product_data){
    return "This product already exists in your cart";
},10,2);
```